# Downloading a webpage containing an iframe element

Tags: c#

I am trying to locate a .mp4 file from this following URL programatically.

https://twitter.com/ERA_fm/status/691183877411328001/video/1

when this page is opened in a web browser and when I debug through inspect element I can see the .mp4 file in the `<video>` tag embedded in an iframe.

Now I have written this code to download the url which is as follows:

```
string siteUrl = "https://twitter.com/ERA_fm/status/691183877411328001/video/1";
string html = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(siteUrl);
```

I see the downloaded source does not contain any video element associated with it, rather there is no iframe element at all.

Comment: Sounds like you should let the javascript run first. Maybe it'll be easier to download the iframe `src` instead

Comment: This library might make it easier for you: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/